# How to take pixel coordinates from an image in c++ using specific conditions

Tags: c++

I want to get (x,Y) co-ordinates from an image where the pixel value is not zero. I got the following error in this code:
error- bad access:

```
camera.cpp
void Camera ::write_uint8_image_1(uint8_image_t *image, int *output)
{
    int index = 1;

     for(uint32_t i = 0; i < image->h; i++)
     {
         for(uint32_t j = 0; j < image->w; j++)
         {
             if(image->data[i * image->w + j] != 0)
                output[index++] = i;
                output[index++] = j;  /* error : bad access */
        }
     }
    output[0] = index;
}


main.cpp
 int output[800] = {0};

    /*print output*/

    C1.write_uint8_image_1(c.output_image, output);
    for (int i = 1; i < output[0]; i++)
        std::cout<< output[i] << " , ";
```

Comment: Probably you need a curly brace after `if` and `index` should start from `0` ?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. But it does not work.

Comment: There could be other issue as well, may be your `output` doesn't have enough allocated space. Use a debugger, see values of `i`,`j` when it occurs, etc.